# Laravel 8.x - Check if url contains word, in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have created a website with multiple pages and sub-pages, and a top navigation bar with shortcuts in each of them. The navigation bar can determine the current page using the `Request::path()` method directly in the view. Unfortunately, this only applies when the current page is that of the last url parameter.

For example:

```
<a href="{{url('faq')}}" class="{{ Request::path() === 'faq' ? 'current_page_item' : '' }}">FAQ</a>
```

This **^** results in the **FAQ** button of the top navi to be active, when I am into the *`/faq`* page.
However, if I visit the *`/faq/contact`* page, the **FAQ** button is no longer active. How can I fix this ?

I have tried things like:

```
<a href="{{url('faq')}}" class="
    @if (\Request::is('/faq/*'))  
        echo 'current_page_item';
    @endif
">FAQ</a>
```

But then the button does not appear to be active neither when in the `/faq` page nor in the `/faq/contact` page.

Can somebody help ? I would like to avoid using route names if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to lose the first forward slash in your is method

Comment: Don't use `echo` anymore... If you are in blade use `{{ }}` as the documentation explains...

Comment: `is` can take multiple patterns as parameters, so you can pass both if you needed

Comment: Combining all three of your suggestions, I made it work! However, I'd still like it if someone could review my code:

<a href="{{url('faq')}}" class="
                    @ if (\Request::is('faq', 'faq/*'))  
                        {{ 'current_page_item' }}
                    @ endif
                ">FAQ</a>